# Data types to store Integer and Float values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What would be the best data type for storing Integer, Float values altogether in SQL Server.

I need to store normal integer and point (float) decimal values in a single column.

Ex.

```
ColumnNameValues
15
15.5
12.3
17
19.8
```

Comment: `FLOAT` is susceptible to rounding errors - if you need precise math, use `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead - see [relevant MSDN documentation on  `decimal` for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: I will prefer `Numeric(Precision,Scale)`

Comment: The numeric value 17 *is the same as* 17.0 (is the same as 17.00..). It is only *when written in a specific format* that the identical values *look* different. So why must these 'integers' be stored as a different type/formatting from the others?

Comment: yeah but OP wanted to store in same column if we go for numeric then it will give .0 to every value @Fireblade

Comment: @mohan111 - But that doesn't make any difference

Comment: You need to explain further. Why are you doing this? To save space? A float isn't an integer so it shouldn't be stored in the same column. Does it represent the same thing?  A measurement of something?

Answer (score 0):

The best data type for **storing Integer, Float values** altogether in MySQL is : `FLOAT`

Answer (score -1):

if you are going to store in integer it will cut down the values after .(point)but if you going to use Float it will enter all the values whether it is int or float

```
declare @t table (ID float)
insert into @t(id)values (15) ,(15.5),( 12.3),( 17),( 19.8)

select * from @t

declare @t table (ID int)
insert into @t(id)values (15) ,(15.5),( 12.3),( 17),( 19.8)

select * from @t
```

Comment: Am not the downvoter. But have a look at here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: If you take this small things to your heart then you cannot survive in SO. Its just a point leave it. Will give upvote to nullify :)

Answer (score -1):

If you dont need to see the floats correctly in the DB, you could convert the 4 bytes of the float into an integer and store it as an integer. If you want to get it back, read it from the DB then convert it to the float again.

If you dont have the information from the context, if the stored value is an integer or float, it gets a little tricky, you would need to limit the integers or floats somehow, e.g. "sacrifice" one bit to identify, which variation it is.