# column type in PostgreSQL for floating numbers and integers

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in Postgres where data looks something like this:
1.8,
3.4,
7,
1.2,
3
So it has floating numbers in it as well as integers...
What would be the right type for this kind of column?

Numeric data type ?

Comment: please use double precision

Comment: `numeric` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a similar question:** [Data types to store Integer and Float values in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554127/data-types-to-store-integer-and-float-values-in-sql-server)

`Numeric` should work!

Another option is to use a `VARCHAR` column, and store a character representation of the value.

But it seems that you would need some type of indicator as to which type of value was stored. And there's several drawbacks to this approach. One big drawback is that these would allow for "invalid" values to be stored.

Another approach would be to use two columns, one of them `INTEGER`, the other `FLOAT`, and specify a precedence, and allow a NULL value in the `INTEGER` column to represent that the value was stored in the `FLOAT` column.

**For all datatypes in SQL look here:** [Data types to store Integer and Float values in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554127/data-types-to-store-integer-and-float-values-in-sql-server)

Comment: **Never**, ever store numbers in `varchar` columns - that's a really, really bad advice.

Comment: Thnx, what about the "double precision" type  ?